# Rotate 'note' on the canvas to always touch the upper left corner

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The final code  that worked for me was:

```
    <canvas id="bg-admin-canvas" width="500" height="500" style="margin:15px; background:#09F;"></canvas>
    <script>
        var postit = function(width,height,angle){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("bg-admin-canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;                
            var move = width*Math.sin(radians);
            if(angle < 0 ){ ctx.translate(0,-move); }else{ ctx.translate(move,0); }
            ctx.rotate(radians);

            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,height,width/2,height/2);
            gradient.addColorStop(0.05,"rgba(0,0,0,0)");
            gradient.addColorStop(0.5,"rgba(0,0,0,0.3)");
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0,0);
            ctx.lineTo(width, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(width,height);
            ctx.lineTo(width-width*.8,height-height*.02);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0+width*.02,height-height*.02,0+width*.02,(height - height*.2));
            ctx.closePath();
            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,height,width/2,height/2);
            gradient.addColorStop(0,'#f7f8b9');
            gradient.addColorStop(1,'#feffcf');
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(width-width*.8,height-height*.02);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0+width*.02,height-height*.02,0+width*.02,(height - height*.2));
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(width*.05,height-height*.05,width*.1,height-height*.1);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(width*.1,height-height*.07,width-width*.8,height-height*.02);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
            ctx.fill();
            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,height,width*.1,height-height*.1);
            gradient.addColorStop(0,"rgba(222,222,163,0.8)");
            gradient.addColorStop(1,'#feffcf');
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
            ctx.fill();

        }
        postit(300, 300, 10);
    </script>
```

---

Hi,

I made a quick and dirty "post-it" note with html5's canvas and some js.

I want to be able to rotate them anyway I want so I tried to use the translate.  The example below I have a translate of 0,250 just so you could see the whole thing.

Ideally, I know if my canvas was 300,300 then I would
ctx.translate(150,150);
ctx.rotate(-30);
ctx.translate(-150,-150);

Of course since I'm rotating a square it gets cut off.

How would I rotate the square and move it on the canvas so the whole thing is showing but at the very top left edge of the canvas?

I added an image with my thinking of just getting the height of a triangle and moving it that much, but when translated, it doesn't seem to work just right.

I'll paste my whole function so you can look at it, but if you have any ideas, I would appreciate it.  This isn't important, just messing around today.

```
var postit = function(width,height,angle){
            var canvas = jQuery("#bg-admin-canvas").get(0);
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            /*var area = (width*width*Math.sin(angle))/2;
            var h = (area*2) / width + 30;
            ctx.translate(0,h);
            */
            //ctx.translate(150,150);
            ctx.translate(0,250);
            ctx.rotate(angle*Math.PI / 180);
            //ctx.translate(-150,-150);

            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,height,width/2,height/2);
            gradient.addColorStop(0.05,"rgba(0,0,0,0)");
            gradient.addColorStop(0.5,"rgba(0,0,0,0.3)");
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0,0);
            ctx.lineTo(width, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(width,height);
            ctx.lineTo(width-width*.8,height-height*.02);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0+width*.02,height-height*.02,0+width*.02,(height - height*.2));
            ctx.closePath();
            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,height,width/2,height/2);
            gradient.addColorStop(0,'#f7f8b9');
            gradient.addColorStop(1,'#feffcf');
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(width-width*.8,height-height*.02);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0+width*.02,height-height*.02,0+width*.02,(height - height*.2));
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(width*.05,height-height*.05,width*.1,height-height*.1);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(width*.1,height-height*.07,width-width*.8,height-height*.02);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
            ctx.fill();
            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,height,width*.1,height-height*.1);
            gradient.addColorStop(0,"rgba(222,222,163,0.8)");
            gradient.addColorStop(1,'#feffcf');
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
            ctx.fill();
        }
        postit(300, 300, -35);
```

[image: Postit from HTML5 Canvas]

---

MORE INFO

Phrog, I think you know what I'm trying to do. This image shows what I want to do:
[image]
Now, the only thing is, I want to be able to pass in any width and height and angle and make the adjustment on the fly.

As an example with the following code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("bg-admin-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,360,true); ctx.fill();
ctx.translate(50, 50);
ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,360,true); ctx.fill();
ctx.translate(-25, -25);
ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,360,true); ctx.fill();
```

I get the following image:
[image]
Now, if I add a rotate in there like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("bg-admin-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,360,true); ctx.fill();
ctx.translate(50, 50);
ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,360,true); ctx.fill();
ctx.rotate(30*Math.PI/180);
ctx.translate(-25, -25);
ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,360,true); ctx.fill();
```

I now have a sloped coordinates as the result is:
[image]

As I found, this is because the coordinates are no longer horizontal and vertical.

So, with this rotated coordinate structure, I can't figure out how to move my square (which could be any size and rotated at any angle) back to the left and top (so it fits in as little space as possible)

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short:

- Translate the context in the Y direction only to put the corner where it should be.
- Rotate the context around this offset point.
- Draw your object at 0,0.

Here is an interactive, working example, which you can see online here:
http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_rotate_square_in_corner.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en"><head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
  <title>HTML5 Canvas Rotate Square in Corner</title> 
  <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
    body { background:#eee; margin:2em; text-align:center }
    canvas { display:block; margin:auto; background:#fff; border:1px solid #ccc }
  </style> 
</head><body> 
<canvas width="250" height="200"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
  var can = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#600'; ctx.lineWidth = 2; ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0'
  document.body.onmousemove = function(evt){
    var w=140, h=120;
    var angle = evt ? (evt.pageX - can.offsetLeft)/100 : 0;
    angle = Math.max(Math.min(Math.PI/2,angle),0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height); ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(1,w*Math.sin(angle)+1);
    ctx.rotate(-angle);
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.restore();
  };
  document.body.onmousemove();
</script> 
</body></html>
```

### Analysis

[image: Diagram showing a rectangle rotated counter-clockwise, with corner A on the Y axis at 0,12 and corner B on the X axis at 20,0; construction D is at 20,12, and the angle DAB is labeled with a lowercase 'a']

In the above diagram, point **A** is the upper-left corner of our post-it note and point **B** is the upper-right corner. We have rotated the post-it note **-a** radians from the normal angle (clockwise rotations are positive, counter-clockwise are negative).

We can see that the point **A** stays on the *y* axis as the post-it rotates, so we only need to calculate how far down the *y* axis to move it. This distance is expressed in the diagram as **BD**. From trigonometry we know that
*sin(a) = **BD** / **AB***

Rearranging this formula gives us
***BD** = **AB** * sin(a)*

We know that **AB** is the width of our post-it note. A few details:

1. Because our angle will be expressed as a negative number, and the *sin* of a negative number yields a negative result, but because we want a positive result, we must either negate the result
   ***BD** = -**AB** * sin(-a)*
   or just 'cheat' and use a positive angle:
   ***BD** = **AB** * sin(a)*
2. We need to remember to translate our context *before* we rotate it, so that we first move directly down the axis to establish our origin at the right spot.
3. Remember that rotations in HTML5 Canvas use radians (not degrees). If you want to rotate by 20 degrees, you need to convert that to radians by multiplying by `Math.PI/180`:

   ```
    ctx.rotate( 20*Math.PI/180 );
   ```

*This also applies to the `arc` command; you should be doing `ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,false)`; for a full circle.*

Comment: This is great work in a quick time.  Unfortunately, it doesn't really help me tranlate the slope of the new coordinates. I just now realized that when you rotate, the canvas interprets any more tranlates on a slope and not in a horizontal veritical fashion.  That just really confused me.  Might be time for a  trig refresher.

Comment: @SenicaGonzalez You can `restore()` your context after drawing the rotated rect—or just manually unrotate it—if you don't want to continue working in the transformed coordinate system. I sadly don't understand the problem you are having (I don't know what _"translate the slope of the new coordinates"_ means), but I'm glad you seem to have found an answer that works for you.

Comment: @Phrogz.  Yeah, I know I can restore it or unrotate it, but I want to keep the rectangle rotated, but just move it back like you showed in your example to the left edge and top edge.  However, after I rotate the rectangle, the x,y coordinates are not in an up and down fashion relative to the screen, the coordinates are also rotated.  So I'm failing at trying to figure out how to get my rotated rectangle and rotated coordinates to the point where I want them.

Comment: @Senica Well, feel free to post an updated, not-working-but-self-contained example for further help. (Paring down the code to the minimum to show you problem would make it easier to assist you.)

Comment: @Phrog, seriously, thanks for your help.  Even though this is really just for fun, I really get into these things.  I added some more info.  I didn't really add any code as it wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: @Phrogz, reading back through your example, forget me trying to put the square back somwhere, I guess I don't know how to figure where the starting corner should be as you suggested to be able to rotate from that point and draw.

Comment: @Senica I've updated my answer with a derivation of the code I'm using. (I also updated the code and example to keep the 'top' of the note pointing towards the corner.)

Comment: Be sure to check out the [updated demo on my site](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_rotate_square_in_corner.html), as I've added text and a couple other transformations (a rotating but always-offset shadow). If this answer helps you solve your problem 'cleanly', know that you can change your 'acceptance' tick to another answer if you like. ;)

Comment: @Phrogz.  This is brilliant. From my first post, I feel like I was on the right track to start with, but somehow got sidetracked trying to move the canvas and stuff.  Thanks for straightening me out!  This rocks!

Comment: Well, I really hope this helps some people out.

Answer (score 2):

You should create you canvas element and then rotate it using CSS. It would keep your canvas intact and only rotate the element itself.

Here is some example css rules:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
```

Refer to http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Comment: I find this to be a cheezy way out ;)  But given that I can't figure out the slope coordinates, it will have to do for now.

Comment: I actually think it's a better approach. Rotating elements inside the canvas is probably done at the pixel level (each pixel is calculated independently) and would be more resource-demanding. This solution rotates  the entire block and is probably faster. Guess you're good with it.